# How can I skip about \t and \n and all the another special chars of white-spaces in c?

Tags: c, special-characters

Given string like: `ab \t \nc` how can i ignore the white-spaces and to get `abc` in c?
I know how to skip about really tab and white-space:

```
if(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] = '\t')
```

but if I pass string that with `\t` strictly, so i will get `str[i]=\` and `str[i+1]=t`. So how can I catch these cases?

For example:

```
char* str = "abcd \n \t ef   ";
char* str_clear = filter(str); // need to be "abcdef".
```

And I asking about how to write the filter function (like that i write above, i know how skip about ' ' and '' , but how can I catch "\n" and "\t"?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73735111/should-4-while-loops-be-placed-in-a-macro-or-function-c-c) your question? If not, read the comments and get some ideas.

Comment: `isspace( str[i] )` from ctype.h

Comment: @EugeneSh. No, see again the question - i edited it

Comment: @AviBerger it's still not works. `./main "\t123"`.  and: `char* s = argv[i]; while(isspace(*s)) { s++;} ` not skip about `\t` because that s[0] is ` \  ` and s[1] is `t`

Comment: That's how you tell if it's a character you want to eliminate. You still have to do the work to allocate and build your new string. (and free it when done, if you are dynamically allocating the replacement string.)

Comment: Re “if I pass string that with `\t` strictly, so i will get `str[i]=\` and `str[i+1]=t`”: No. When `\t` appears in source code as `'\t'` or inside quote marks (`"`), the resulting constant or string has a tab character, not a slash and a t. Edit your post to clarify your question: Are you just trying to remove space, tab, and new-line characters, or do you need to process `\` and `t` characters that are **actually** in the source string?

Comment: Also, can `filter` change the array it is passed and return it as the result string or does it need to allocate memory for a new string?

Comment: @AviBerger No, you can see that given "\t123" and the `while` that i write above, you never will do `s++`..

Comment: @EricPostpischil try it yourselft: put the following code in some file and gcc it to output file (that it's name is `name` for example) `int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 char* str = argv[1];
 printf("|%c|\n", str[0]);
}` ...... and open for example bash file (it's name is f1) with this content: `#!/bin/bash

./main "\t123"`

Comment: That \t in the command line argument is not in source code and not whitespace which you said you wanted to skip. It is an actual '\' followed by a 't'.  This is @EricPostpischil's question. My comment was about detecting whitespace only, not other stuff.

Comment: @user20007266: Passing a command-line argument of `"\t123"` is not using `\t` inside quotes in source code. To type a tab inside quotes in a command-line argument, press Control-V Tab.

Comment: @EricPostpischil so how for example if i pass to strtol function this string "\t  \n 123" so it's ignore `\t` and `\n` ?

Comment: Second part of your condition uses **assignment** not **is equal**...

Comment: @AviBerger You meet maybe way like `isspace` to do it in case of command line argument ?

Comment: isspace is only about distinguishing whitespace. Since you are concerned with stuff other than whitespace, you need to use something in addition or in place of it. You can check out the other isXXX functions from ctype.h and @Fe203's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The second part of the condition in the OP uses `=` where `==` is (apparently) intended.

Here ya go...

```
if(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\t' || ( str[i] == '\\' && str[i+1] == 't' ) )
```

Better:

```
#include <ctype.h> // use this

if( isspace( str[i] )
|| ( str[i] == '\\' && ( str[i+1] == 't' || str[i+1] == 'n' ) ) )
```

Can't really see the use for this, but the OP clearly says this is wanted.

It's a string, so "sniffing" the next character is allowed. Worst case the next character is '\0'.

If the source string is being *compacted* into another buffer;

```
if( isspace( str[i] ) )
    i++; // ignore one character
else if( str[i] == '\\' && ( str[i+1] == 't' || str[i+1] == 'n' ) )
    i += 2; // ignore two characters
else
    dst[ j++ ] = str[ i++ ];
```